# N1QL join with id as Array,Cocuhbase

Tags: couchbase, sql++

I have json like below

```
 "User|255": {
        "_id": 255,
        "_type": "User",
        "children": [
          482,
          636,
          637,
          638,
          651,
          673,
          872
            ],
          "created": "2016-02-01T18:30:00.000Z",
    }
```

now I want to join as with it like **`on keys['User|TOSTRING(children[*])']`**

I have tried like below

```
select Users._id from default U1 join default Users 
on keys ("User|"||TOSTRING(U1.children[*])) 
where Campaign._type='User' and _id= 255
```

But it is not working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you go.

```
ON KEYS ARRAY 'User|' || TO_STRING(c) FOR c IN U1.children END
```